# I have a process (left) that is stuck, and I can't kill it. (kill -9 does not work), what to do?

Tags: process, kill, lftp

I have a process that I ran under a Tmux session that I cannot kill.

I have tried `kill`, `kill -9`, and a few other kill numbers, without it having any effect.

I killed the tmux session successfully but the process lives on.

It does not appear that it has any parents that I can find using different variations of `ps`.

I could use some help.

Here is what `ps` gives:

```
root     18939  1.2  0.0  63492 11148 ?        D    Jul22  53:01 lftp -p 22 -u user,password sftp://somewhere.com
```

Comment: What makes you think this process exists? Is it showing in a process manager? If so copy-paste the output.

Answer (score 3):

Your process has the D flag, and is stuck in the D state. You can not kill it, it is by design. You can reboot if you want it gone.

The D state is un-interruptible (TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE) state of a process.
You can wait or reboot.

See previous [discussion here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423521/process-permanently-stuck-on-d-state)